# Oracle/JDBC: Problem with correct Timezone of rows

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a table TAB with a timestamp (DT) and a value (VAL) per row.

```
 DT           NOT NULL   TIMESTAMP(0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
 VAL          NOT NULL   NUMBER
```

I try to read and get the timestamps in UTC.

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC (dt) AS dtm, val FROM mytab;
```

Result in Sqlplus looks ok to me.

```
DTM                 VAL
---------------------------
30.03.19 23:00:00   124
31.03.19 00:00:00   125
31.03.19 01:00:00   126
31.03.19 02:00:00   127
31.03.19 03:00:00   128
31.03.19 04:00:00   129
31.03.19 05:00:00   130
```

Now I do the same in Java/JDBC.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp ("dtm");
java.util.Date dt = rs.getDate ("dtm"); 
java.util.Date tm = rs.getTime ("dtm");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ts.toInstant ().atZone (ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println("ts="+ts.toString() + "     val="+rs.getDouble("wert") +
     "   dt=" + dt.toString() + "    tm=" + tm.toString() +"      zdt="+zdt);
```

And the result is not what I expected regarding timezones.

```
ts=2019-03-30 23:00:00.0     val=124.0   dt=2019-03-30    tm=23:00:00      zdt=2019-03-30T22:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 00:00:00.0     val=125.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=00:00:00      zdt=2019-03-30T23:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 01:00:00.0     val=126.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=01:00:00      zdt=2019-03-31T00:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 03:00:00.0     val=127.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=02:00:00      zdt=2019-03-31T01:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 03:00:00.0     val=128.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=03:00:00      zdt=2019-03-31T01:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 04:00:00.0     val=129.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=04:00:00      zdt=2019-03-31T02:00Z
ts=2019-03-31 05:00:00.0     val=130.0   dt=2019-03-31    tm=05:00:00      zdt=2019-03-31T03:00Z
```

Why does ts have a double 3? I would expect it to be in UTC.
The only correct time is in tm.

Why is that? Whats the problem here?

JRE 1.8
Oracle 12c
Linux with local timezone CET/CEST

Comment: I'd suggest that you switch to the `java.time.LocalTime`, `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalDateTime` introduced in Java 8 (and in JDBC 4.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone CET/CEST switches to Daylight Savings Time on 2019-03-31 at 02:00:00, so it skips from 02:00:00 to 03:00:00.

`getDate` returns a `java.sql.Date` that is a `java.util.Date` at 2019-03-31 at midnight, so no DST.

`getTime` returns a `java.sql.Time` that is a `java.util.Date` at 1970-01-01 at given time, so no DST.

`getTimestamp` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` that is a `java.util.Date` at given date and time, so DST is applied, changing 02:00 to 03:00. However, the values from the database don't have time zone, so remaining values don't get shifted. This is a flaw in the handling of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

Converting `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.time.Instant` will adjust for DST, so mangles the times.

Note that `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` does not store a time zone, it just tell the client API to convert to session time zone on your behalf. The actual value in the database depends on the database time zone, not the client time zone or the session time zone.

Answer (score 1):

*From Java Doc:* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html
Timestamp, A thin wrapper around java.util.Date that allows the JDBC API to identify this as an SQL TIMESTAMP value. It adds the ability to hold the SQL TIMESTAMP fractional seconds value, by allowing the specification of fractional seconds to a precision of nanoseconds. A Timestamp also provides formatting and parsing operations to support the JDBC escape syntax for timestamp values.

The precision of a Timestamp object is calculated to be either:

- 19 , which is the number of characters in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
- 20 + s , which is the number of characters in the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.[fff...] and s represents the scale of the given Timestamp, its fractional seconds precision.

There are many ways to format the timestamp and one such example can be following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf("2019-03-30 23:00:00.0");
System.out.println(sdf.format(ts));
```